# Encoding $_GET variable URL ignores ampersand "&" character

Tags: php, url, get

So im trying to get an url from the address bar that looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/url.php?name=http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false
```

I'm using the $_GET variable to read it right off the URL my code is as follows

```
$arc = rawurlencode($_GET['name']);
echo "URL: $arc";
```

This only returns

```
URL: http://imgur.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3
```

It 's missing the &secure=false

What i want it to look:

```
 URL: http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false
```

I have tried urlencode, rawurlencode with no avail, i have looked in google a number of forums and stackoverflow none of the answer help, any ideas? Thanks!

urlencode shows this:

URL: http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com

so i cant have that either!

Comment: The problem you are seeing here is that name is one of the GET parameters, and secure is the other. So your request would have to be rawurlencoded PRIOR to being sent as a request, not AFTER.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to `urlencode()` before constructing the URL, ie:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/url.php?name=".urlencode('http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false');
```

This way, you will be able obtain the full URL as a `name` GET parameter from `$_GET['name']`.

#### Explanation:

Without `urlencode()` it when constructing the URL, PHP would treat is as 2 separate parameters, separated by `&`:

1. `$_GET['name']`
   which is `http://imgur.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3` for your case
2. `$_GET['secure']`
   which is `false` for your case

#### Alternatively:

From your comment, it seems that you do not have control for the URL construction. You can get the full `$_GET` in a single string using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$name = http_build_query($_GET);
```

You would then obtain:

```
echo $name; // name=http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false

// which you would then may want to strip away the first 'name='
$name = substr($name, strlen('name='));

echo $name; // to obtain http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false
```

Comment: how can i obtain the url from the address bar and input it into .urlencode()? without using &_GET?

Comment: If you constructed the URL, you should construct it properly. Otherwise, you can obtain the 2 separate `$_GET` parameters and glue them back.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how you can get all the params in a single string using `http_build_query()`.

Comment: `http_build_query()` converts an array into a query-string. Do you mean `parse_url()` here?

Comment: Indeed, i have no control on the URL construction, using http_build_query gets me this when i echo:
http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com

Comment: You could also use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead of `parse_url()` as you're treating it as a string and not an array.

Comment: After revising my code for hours and hours, (i'm new to php and programming), i realized i do have control on the URL construction! I did the first step and urlencode during the construction and it works! thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

The original URL, `http://mysite.com/url.php?name=http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false`, contains two query-string parameters: `name` and `secure`. The `&` in the query-string belongs to the *full* URL, not the URL in the `name` parameter.

If you have control over this value, when declaring the link/URL, use PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode the full name value, such as:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/url.php?name=" . urlencode("=http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false");
```

This will properly encode the `name` parameter and your `$arc = $_GET['name'];` will work as desired.

If you do not have control over setting the value and are simply parsing something you're receiving, you can split the given string on the `name=` parameter and assume everything else after it is part of `name`:

```
$splitQuery = split('name=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$arc = $splitQuery[1];
```

To decode the encoded URL, after you've accessed it, use PHP's [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode):

```
$arc = urldecode($_GET['name']); // assuming you're properly encoding the `name` parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot encode the URL, you can get the current URI with this code:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

that in your case, the $url is :

```
/url.php?name=http://test.com/format.jsp?id=738ths3&secure=false
```

Then you can split it with explode and validate it and take the GET params from it.